# Writing overlapping samples (audio files) in one AudioClip

Tags: unity-game-engine, sample

Is it possible to write multiples overlapping samples in one AudioClip ? If yes, how ?
( http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/AudioClip.SetData.html )

I have a situation where I have a lot of sounds played at the same time. On top of that I need to apply some specific effects to that (Reverb on AudioListener). After a lot of iterations I found that I need to write dynamically the samples in an AudioClip.

But how are you supposed to script the overlapping part so that it's not just overriding the previous clips ?

Many thanks !

Comment: +1 Depends on how many sounds, maybe using several different `AudioSource` components makes life easier.

Comment: A lot. I'm already using 10-16 different AudioSources, that's not the point. In this context it's a matter of filling the clips dynamically in these AudioSources.